# Is there a way to fill in a contour in a binary image?

Tags: python, image

I'm new to Python and I need help with what is, hopefully, an easy problem.

I have equations for all sides of a polygon.
I intend to use this equations to plot dots in a binary image in order to get a contour of such polygon.

I think that in Matlab I could use imfill.m to fill in this polygon. However, I don't know if this function recognizes a smaller contour inside a larger one.
When this happens, I want my filled image to have a hole in it correspondent to the smaller contour.

Will imfill.m ignore the smaller contour and fill the hole as well?
If not, is there a similar function in Python?

Basically, what I'm looking for is a function or algorithm in Python capable of filling multiple polygons in the same image while avoiding possible holes.

Thank you for your attention.